# Decentralised execution of jobs in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I came across multi job plugin which helps in executing jobs parallelly but I want to reduce the load on server.So I want to decentralised the execution of jobs.

Is it possible in jenkins to achieve this.If yes then how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a comprehensive description how setup [distributed builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) in Jenkins.

You can also try to create build [pipelines](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=121).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

You can run both sequential and parallel by using this plugin.